# Convert DOCX files to PDF files using PDFsharp or MigraDoc in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a console application in VB.
Today I'm using PDFsharp (http://www.pdfsharp.net/) to merge PDF files
like this:

```
Private Sub mergePdfFiles(pdfFiles As String(), output As String)
    Dim out As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
    Try
        For Each file As String In pdfFiles
            Dim inputDoc As PdfDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(file,IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
            Dim count As Integer = inputDoc.PageCount

            For idx As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                Dim page As PdfPage = inputDoc.Pages(idx)
                out.AddPage(page)
            Next
        Next
        out.Save(output)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

This works fine.
Now I want to convert DOCX files to PDF, but it seems that PDFsharp can't do it.
I understand that MigraDoc can do it

> MigraDoc Foundation the Open Source .NET library that easily creates documents based on an object model with paragraphs, tables, styles, etc. and renders them into PDF or RTF.

But I didn't manage to do it. The samples are not very clear and is for C#.
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/DocumentViewer-sample.ashx

For example:

```
//create RTF file From document
private void miRtf_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  RtfDocumentRenderer rtf = new RtfDocumentRenderer();
  rtf.Render(this.pagePreview.Document, "test.rtf", null);

  Process.Start("test.rtf");
}
```

In VB I try with `Me` instead of `this` but I don't have pagePreview.

How can I convert DOCX files to PDF files in VB using MigraDoc or PDFsharp?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any file to MigraDoc as long as you can parse the input file.

You have to write code that reads the DOCX files and extracts tables, text etc. from them.

The MigraDoc documentation does not say that MigraDoc can import RTF or DOC or DOCX or HTML. You can use MigraDoc to create new documents.

Comment: Thank you, I want to convert docx to pdf using migraDoc, not to convert to migraDoc.

Comment: MigraDoc can render documents in PDF or RTF format. But first you have to create a MigraDoc document. So yes, you want to convert DOCX to MigraDoc in order to create PDF files with your DOCX contents.